# Angular 2+ multiple observable data services

Tags: angular, architecture, rxjs, flux

In my knowledge, there are 2 ways to manage application state:

- Flux like architecture (Redux, ngrx,...)
- Observable data services ([This](http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/)  article)

My app uses the second one.

---

I have an `AuthService` that manage users `AuthState` (`id`, `accessToken`,...)

Almost all other services need to access this `AuthState`. Thus, in other services, there are private fields that store this `AuthState` and I have to sync data state between them.

---

Questions:

- Is this kind of denormalized data a normal behavior in multiple observable data services?
- Is centralized data store (Flux) the only way to manage state in a normalized way? If not, how should I improve my architecture?

Comment: The data is not denormalized if other services only hold a reference to `AuthService` right?

Comment: Yes, other services hold a reference to `AuthService` through DI. The data is gotten through subscribe to the state in the `AuthService`.